# A concise way to say "none of the elements of an array are None"?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What's a concise python way to say

```
if <none of the elements of this array are None>:
   # do a bunch of stuff once
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not simply,

```
None not in lst
```

Comment: Perfect - reads beautifully what it's supposed to say - I knew there must be a nice way :)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I agree that both clearly express in English what they mean, which is a big plus.   Which is _more_ like English appears to me to be a personal preference: I think I would tend not to commence with a negation "if it is not the case that None is in the list" is less like what I would say than "if None isn't in the list".   But very much personal preference.  I'd have upvoted your answer if it were still there :)

Comment: I tend to think that `if None not in lst` reads more like Python, though.

Comment: When it's unclear which of two forms is more readable, [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) often has guidance. It explicitly suggests `spam is not eggs` in place of `not spam is eggs`, which implies `spam not in eggs` in place of `not spam in eggs`. (Also, the `is not` and `not in` operators wouldn't have been created in the first place if the devs didn't think code using them was more readable.)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: it produces *exactly* the same Python bytecode.

Answer (score 7):

The [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) builtin is nice for this.  Given an iterable, it returns `True` if all elements of the iterable evaluate to `True`.

```
if all(x is not None for x in array):
  # your code
```

Comment: That's cool, but I find it hard to read what it means - it makes me think, which hurts my head :D

Comment: To me, it's super easy to read -- but I use the `all` builtin and generators a lot, so that may explain it. :-)

Comment: Yep - I can imagine that.  Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @GreenAsJade: Sometimes it helps to demorgan it as `if not any(x is None for x in array)`. You can naturally read `not any(…)` as "none of …". Of course in this case, there's a much simpler solution ([Jared's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26476967/908494)), but in general it's worth trying.

Comment: @GreenAsJade: Actually, now that I think about it, Sam Mussmann has already implicitly demorganed it… and many people would do so without thinking about it (at least I would, and Sam did…), so it's definitely worth learning how the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

Of course in this case, [Jared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476967/908494) is obviously the shortest, and also the most readable. And it has other advantages (like automatically becoming O(1) or O(log N) if you switch from a list to a set or a SortedSet). But there will be cases where that doesn't work, and it's worth understanding how to get from your English-language statement, to the most direct translation, to the most idiomatic.

You start with "none of the elements in array are None".

Python doesn't have a "none of" function. But if you think about it, "none of" is exactly the same as "not any of". And it does have an "any of" function, `any`. So, the closest thing to a direct translation is:

```
if not any(element is None for element in array):
```

However, people who use `any` and `all` frequently (whether in Python, or in symbolic logic) usually get used to using [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) to translate to a "normal" form. An `any` is just an iterated disjunction, and the negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations, so, this translates into [Sam Mussmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476953/908494):

```
if all(element is not None for element in array):
```

Comment: Could you provide an example where breaking `None not in array` is useful?

Comment: +1 for helping the lightglobe to go on about how to "English read": read that all case!   As soon as I see it that way I can't image how it was hard for me to read it before ... and yet it was.   Weird!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I don't know what you mean by "breaking". Cases where a simple `__contains__` test don't work are obvious, like `if not any(element < 30 for element in array)`, but I don't think you'd call those "breaking" `not in`, they're just cases where it doesn't work because it's not appropriate.

Comment: ok. I thought yours *"there will be cases where that doesn't work"* refer to cases where `__contains__` lies about `None`. For a more general question such as "a concise way to say none of the elements of an array are <condition>", you are right: `not any(<condition> for item in lst)` or `all(not <condition> for item in lst)` -- both work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use all

```
all(i is not None for i in l)
```